# Unable to get images from the images folder using img tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display images for each object inside `categoryDictonary` and later display it using the html tag `<img src=items.image />`. However I am unable to get the desired image.
What am I doing wrong?

I would've just used links to images but the links are very very lengthy and they make the code look/feel clumsy as well.
I think its good practice to have a seperate folder for images but I'm unable to implement the same.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  var categoryDictonary = {
    Marvel: [
      {
        name: "WandaVision",
        image: "Images/Wanda.jfif",
        rating: 10
      },
      { name: "Loki", image: "Loki.jfif", rating: 9.5 },
      { name: "Moon Knight", image: "Images/MoonKnight.jfif", rating: 8 }
    ],
    SitComs: [
      {
        name: "Brooklyn 99",
        image: "Images/Wanda",
        rating: 10
      },
      {
        name: "Bing Bang Theory",
        image: "Images/Loki",
        rating: 7
      },
      {
        name: "Friends",
        image: "Image/Wanda",
        rating: 7
      }
    ]
  };

  var categories = Object.keys(categoryDictonary);
  var [category, setCategory] = useState("Marvel");
  function ClickHandler({ item }) {
    console.log(item);
    setCategory(item);
    console.log("Categoty is" + category);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>TV Show Ratings</h2>
      <h3>Check out my ratings on some of the most popular TV Shows</h3>
      <ul>
        {categories.map((item) => {
          return (
            <li
              id="Categories"
              key={item}
              onClick={() => ClickHandler({ item })}
            >
              {item}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
//List to display all shows of a given category
      <ul id="ShowList">
        {categoryDictonary[category].map((items) => {
          return (
            <li id="Shows" key={items.name}>
//Gives the name of the show
              <div>{items.name}</div>
//Gives the image of the show
              <div>
                <img src={items.image} />
              </div>
//Gives the rating of the show
              <div>Rating:{items.rating}</div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the corresponding output to my code:

[image: Current output of my code]

Comment: Try changing `image: "Images/Wanda",` to be `image: "/Images/Wanda",`. Also, it might be worth adding an image of the folder structure to confirm the path from the root folder, since I guess these are stored in the public folder right now?

Comment: We don't know what the URL displayed in the address bar is. We don't know what the URL of the images are (or even if you've done anything that would give them URLs). We therefore have no way of working out what the resolved URL the browser is using to try to find the image is *or* comparing it to what you need.

Comment: Where are these images exactly? Since you aren't including them in your React code but setting src to a string, they need to be inside the public folder of your project. (also, as a complete aside: you should use `.map((item) =>` (singular) since that's what it is: a single item)

Comment: You should require these images: `<img src={require(items.image)}`  .../>

Comment: @maswerdna — You can't `require` variables in webpack since it needs to compute them at build time and they don't get values until runtime.

Comment: @jake I tried changing image: "Images/Wanda" to image:"/Images/Wanda" however it made no difference. Here is an image of the folder structure though https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFFlU.png

Comment: @maswerdna This seems to be in the right direction but it shows and error saying Could not find dependency: 'Images' relative to '/src/App.js'

Comment: @ChrisG I have attached an image showing the folder structure and yes I shall change items to item ty :)

Comment: Hi  Sorry I edited the question while you were adding the folder structure. Sorry for the inconvenience, please add it again.

Comment: React is frontend. It runs in the browser. Your Images folder is not even inside `src`, but even that wouldn't work with your current approach. The browser cannot load arbitrary files from the backend, that would be a massive security issue. That's why the `public` folder exists, so you can allow access to certain files. Note that this isn't even really a React issue. You're setting a src of `Images/abc.jfif` so the browser expects the files at something like `localhost:3000/Images/abc.jfif`

Comment: From looking at the folder layout, you likely need to move the image folder into the public folder and that will then allow you to access the images. e.g. `<ROOT_URL>/Images/abc.png`

Comment: @SiddharthReddy you should have the images folder relative to the /src/App/js, you may want to consider making the image folder a subdir of the /src dir